# Axioms for sheaf cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $X$ a topological space. Define a *sheafy cohomology theory* (see [here](http://www-math.sp2mi.univ-poitiers.fr/~sarti/corso_Perego.pdf)) to be a collection of functors $\mathrm{H}^q:\mathrm{Sh}(X;R\mathrm{Mod})\to R\mathrm{Mod}$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:

- If $q<0$, then $\mathrm{H}^q(\mathscr{F})=0$. If $q=0$, then there is an isomorphism $\alpha_\mathscr{F}:\mathrm{H}^0(\mathscr{F})\to\mathscr{F}(X)$.
- <strike>If $\mathscr{F}$ is flasque or fine, then $\mathrm{H}^q(\mathscr{F})=0$ for $q>0$.</strike>
- If $0\to\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{G}\to\mathscr{H}\to0$ is a short exact sequence of sheaves, then there is a long exact sequence:
  $$\cdots\to\mathrm{H}^q(\mathscr{F})\to\mathrm{H}^q(\mathscr{G})\to\mathrm{H}^q(\mathscr{H})\to\mathrm{H}^{q+1}(\mathscr{F})\to\cdots$$

My question is as follows: is ordinary sheaf cohomology $\mathrm{H}^q(X,\mathscr{F})$ the only sheafy cohomology theory (removing the flasque sheaf requirement)? If not, are there any other examples of a sheafy cohomology theory?

Comment: Yes, use that every sheaf embeds in a flasque sheaf and induct on q.

Comment: The uniqueness theorem can be found for example in Lang's "Algebra" XX.7

Comment: @Daniel I used a simple diagram chasing argument with the short five lemma and got the required isomorphism. Thanks!

Comment: This was a silly question on my part; could it be deleted/closed?

Comment: You should ask Tyler.  It would be unfair for me to delete his contribution without his consent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to the updated question: yes, there are other cohomology theories. For example, if $H$ is ordinary sheaf cohomology, then we can define a new sheaf cohomology theory $K$ by $K^q({\cal F}) = H^q({\cal F}) \times H^{q-1}({\cal F})$. (This is a special instance of a hypercohomology construction which is genuinely important in some areas.)

With respect to the original question: A. Grothendieck, "Sur quelques points d’algèbre homologique" (the Tohoku paper); Cartan-Eilenberg, "Homological algebra".

Comment: That's a pretty neat example. Thanks!

Comment: Me and Elden had a discussion on facebook - isn't $\mathrm{H}^q(\mathcal{F})=\prod^q_{i=n}\mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ also a sheafy cohomology theory in the revised definition?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I'm a little bit confused by your suggestion, because it seems that such a definition would cut off some of the long exact sequence if $n > 0$, and if $n < 0$ it would mean the same as if $n=0$ (where it is true).

Comment: Yeah, I see that my suggestion wasn't right. Thanks!